# Como vincular os Forms criados no Django com os formulários já criados na template HTML?

Tags: html, django, formulário

Comecei a ver sobre formulários no Django, só que eu já havia criado nos *templates* do meu projeto os formulários com todos os `inputs` necessários. Com a criação dos `forms` no Django existe uma maneira de eu vincular cada `form` a um formulário já criado no *template* para que ele não crie outro `form` com mais `inputs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como explicado [nessa seção da documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template), você não precisa usar o método de geração automática do formulário (`{{ form.as_p }}`) se você não quiser. Basta que o seu template possua os campos `input` corretos (com os `name`s apropriados a cada campo).

Uma maneira de descobrir qual o formato esperado por um `Form` específico é - no shell por exemplo - chamar o método `as_p` e ver qual é sua saída:

```python
>>> f = ContactForm(auto_id=True)
>>> print(f.as_p())
<p><label for="subject">Subject:</label> <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" maxlength="100" /></p>
<p><label for="message">Message:</label> <input type="text" name="message" id="message" /></p>
<p><label for="sender">Sender:</label> <input type="email" name="sender" id="sender" /></p>
<p><label for="cc_myself">Cc myself:</label> <input type="checkbox" name="cc_myself" id="cc_myself" /></p>
```

<sub>[Fonte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#ref-forms-api-configuring-label)</sub>

A partir daí você pode verificar se o seu template criado manualmente está de acordo com o que é esperado pelo `Form`, e se estiver você pode usá-lo sem problemas.